# Object composition in Solidity

Tags: oop, solidity, smartcontracts

How does object composition work in Solidity? I haven't found a comprehensive guide, and all examples seem to deal with hello world level stuff or ERC20 token implementations.

1. Can I have a contract with public properties which are other contracts?
2. Can these contract instances passed as function arguments between contracts?

Comment: This should go on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com, so I voted to close. That said you'd use an address that points to the deployed contract, which you can store in properties, pass around as you see fit etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both of these questions - a simple example to illustrate would look something like this:

```
    contract HelperContract {
        function foo() public pure returns(uint) {
            return(0);
        }
    }

    contract MainContract {
        HelperContract helperContract;

        function MainContract(address helperAddress) public {
            helperContract = HelperContract(helperAddress);
        }

        function bar() public view returns(uint) {
            return helperContract.foo();
        }
    }
```

Upon deploying `HelperContract`, and then creating an instance of `MainContract` with the now-deployed HelperContract's address, we can call `bar`, which will in turn call `foo`.

You can copy-paste this code into [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js) and verify that's the case pretty quickly.

If you'd like to see a real world example beyond the `Hello world!` type, you can view the [CryptoKitties](https://www.cryptokitties.co/) source [here](https://ethfiddle.com/09YbyJRfiI), where they use this type of pattern.

It's quite a bit of code to dig through, but you can look for the `KittyAuction` contract, which contains methods `setSaleAuctionAddress` and `setSiringAuctionAddress`. These functions set references to separately deployed `SaleClockAuction` and `SiringClockAuction` contracts respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using composition you can write an upgradeable smart contract. Let's say you want to write a bank contract. for this you should be separating the state from the base contract logic in case in the future your base contract logic gets bugs and you will still be able to keep the state:

```
contract BankData {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    function SetBalance(address address_, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        balances[address_] = amount;
    }
function GetBalance(address address_) public returns (uint256){
        return balances[address_];
    }
}
```

> Composition is one of the fundamental concepts in object-oriented
> programming. It describes a class that references one or more objects
> of other classes in instance variables. This allows you to model a
> has-a association between objects.

```
contract Bank{
    BankDataContract store;

    constructor (uint256 amount, address bankData) {
        store = BankDataContract(bankData);
        store.SetBalance(msg.sender, amount);
    }
    // In case BankDataContract is comprpmised and we killed that contract and deployed a new contract
    function SetNewBankDataAddress(address bankData) public {
        store = BankDataContract(bankdata);
    }
}
```